# What is the meaning of "to work part time and summers"?

Tags: ambiguity

I want to know the exact meaning of "to work part time and summers".
Does this mean someone works part time through the year and works full time in summer? Or does this mean he works part-time only in summer?

Answer (score 1):

In your phrase there are two homogeneous adverbial modifiers. You can paraphrase this phrase into two: 'to work part time' and 'to work in summer'.
So the phrase means that someone has to do a part-time job during the year and a full-time job in summer.

Comment: This is a common contract for students. They work part-time during most of the year (ie after class), and full time during the summer break.